# Does MassTransit's retry brehavior block consuming other messages?

Tags: masstransit

Given MassTransit is configured with a concurrency of 1
*and* has a retry policy of 1 hour for failed messages
*and* the queue starts with 2 messages
*and* consuming the first message fails:

Does MassTransit
1) wait for an hour before trying the first message again while the second message stays enqueued
*or*
2) wait for an hour before trying the first message again while proceeding to try the second message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: 1.

There are two ways to retry using MassTransit.

```
.UseMessageRetry(r => r.???);
```

This is in-memory and keeps the message locked. It is also an active message consumption, so if a prefetch count or concurrency limit is used, it will continue to count towards that limit.

```
.UseScheduledRedelivery(r => r.???);
```

This reschedules the message for delivery using a scheduler (which may be supported by the broker, or via Quartz.NET). It does not block subsequent messages and will enqueue the message for future delivery.

Both are documented [here](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#redelivery).